# @Reference("(service.label=TESTCALL)") Felix SCR annotation error

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

am trying to implement an OSGI service which can serve me as ConfigurationFactory the service implementation has just two properties as shown below.

```
@Property(value="this is service variable property value")
static final String MY_SERVICE_VARIABLE = "service.variable";

@Property(description="Label for this MyService")
private static final String MY_SERVICE_LABEL = "service.label";
```

and am retrieving this service configuration data from an OSGI servlet where i am trying to call this service by below code which compiles fine and retrieves data randomly from the multiple service configuration.

```
@Reference
MyService myservice;
```

But when i wanted to get each configuration data by using the `service.label` and am calling the service by using below code snippet in my OSGI servlet, while compiling am facing the below Error.

```
@Reference("(service.label=TESTCALL)")
MyService myservice;
```

> cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   method value() [ERROR] location:
>   @interface org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `@Reference(target = "(service.label=TESTCALL)")` for AEM 6.x versions, it should compile. I have uploaded the sample POC that i have used earlier at my [gourivar github](https://github.com/gourivar/osgiconfigexample) and the same POC example you can find at my [aemvardhan.wordpress.com](https://aemvardhan.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/how-to-create-aem-osgi-configuration-factory-service/)

Answer (score 0):

Your service is most likely missing the [Service Factory](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#service) annotation. Something like:

```java
    @Service
    @Component(
        metatype=true,label="my service", 
        description="sample my service implementation",
        configurationFactory=true)
        public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService { 

    }
```

Note the **`configurationFactory=true`** attribute. This enables the service to have multiple configurations.

Comment: my service has the annotation included already, and it works when I use it as **@Reference MyService myservice;**,  it fails compilation when I use as **@Reference("(service.label=TESTCALL)") MyService myservice;** because I want to retrieve the configuration data seperated(I.e. All configuration data which is of multiple services)

Comment: Let me ask another way the same question, **how to retrieve the factory service multiple configurations data**.? Any code snippet helps.

Comment: Your approach is fine and without looking at the code snippet (maybe if you can gist it?) I can't see any reason for compilation error. You can try the code snipper from https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2014/08/05/managing-multiple-instances-of-services-osgi-service-factories/ and see if it works as I just tried it locally and it compiles ok (haven't tested the binding but I guess that's not the issue here).

Comment: Yes have referred the same article and trying to achieve **@Reference(“(mailservice.label=INTERNET)”) MailService mailService;** for my service but without any parameters to @Reference annotation it compiles and works fine, if I add the parameter to it as shown above it fails. Will it be possible to share your local code as package? So that I can compare and may be it might help in debugging

Comment: Any chance you are using 6.x as just tried it on 6.x and it doesn't work? I have compiled the sample on 5.6 (copy pasted from the site above) and it works. 6.x with new OSGi has a different way of doing this.

Comment: am using AEM6.2 version.